# Share information between dynamic feature modules

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic, module, modular

I'm starting to use **dynamic feature module** and I have some doubts about how I shared information between modules

For example:

Login Module
- Make a call to the server and get a token to make the other requests
- Get a user session

Movies Module
- Make a request to the server but needs the token that was obtained in the **login module**

Is there any way that the **app project** knows **dynamic feature module**, because dependency realization is inverse

Login Module  <-- app
Movies Module <-- app

Through this dependency relationship I could not call a **login module class** from the **movie module**

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sub-module in the main module like I added linkedin-sdk module in my main module.

Just add sub-module in settings.gradle.kts & build.gradle (module level) files.
setting.gradle.kts file

```
include(":app", ":linkedin-sdk")
```

build.gradle file

```
implementation(project(":linkedin-sdk"))
```

In your case, if you want to access all data of login module then you have to make login module as a sub-module.

Note: It is an example of build.gradle.kts